# vector dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the multiple choice questions (from a past exam, not for marks don't worry) that states:

If $u$ and $v$ are vectors such that $\| u+v \| = 2$ and $\| u-v \|= \sqrt{8}$, then the dot product of $u$ and $v$ is one of the following choices: $-1, 4, -4, \sqrt{2}, 0$

Knowing that:
$$u+v = 2$$
$$u - v = \sqrt{8}$$

I can solve for $u$ and $v$, finding that

$$||v|| = 1-\sqrt{2}$$

$$||u||=\sqrt{8}+1-\sqrt{2}$$

Then knowing that:

$$\| u \| \|v\| \leq \|u \cdot v\|$$

I can determine that the dot product of $u$ and $v$ is $\geq -1$, eliminating the answer of $-4$. This, however, is where I am stuck. I do not know how to progress from here. I am grateful for any help that can be provided.

(The correct answer is $-1$, by the way.)

Comment: @null I think $v$ is supposed to represent $\| v \|$, but they thought $\| u+v \|=\| u \|+\| v \|$ and $\| u-v \|=\| u \|-\| v \|$, which are both not tautologies for vectors $u$ and $v$.

Comment: sorry, yes I meant the length of the vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  Note that norms can be written in terms of dot products:
$$\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}
  \|\v u+\v v\|^2=\v u\cdot\v u+2\v u\cdot\v v+\v v\cdot\v v\ ,\quad
  \|\v u-\v v\|^2=\v u\cdot\v u-2\v u\cdot\v v+\v v\cdot\v v\ .$$
Subtract these equations and use the known values of the norms.

Good luck!

**Comment**.  In fact, you can use this method to find a general formula for $\v u\cdot\v v$ in terms of $\|\v u+\v v\|$ and $\|\v u-\v v\|$.  Try it!